# TCP socket closing but not detected by process

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

I have a server that is meant to allow connections and then based on the message that it receives, the server should do something (not implemented as of yet) however the server should also alert me if a socket is closed which it doesn't.

```
sloop(Listen)->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    io:format("Someone connected"),
    master ! {add,Socket},
    io:format("Point A reached"),
    spawn(fun() -> sloop(Listen) end),
    io:format("Point B reached"),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
             case read(Bin) of
                    {join,Channel} -> 
                                tracker ! {self(),get,Socket},
                                receive 
                                    void -> 
                                        master ! {delete, Socket},
                                        A = lists:dropwhile(fun(A) -> A /= Channel end, registered()),
                                        case A of
                                            [H|_] -> H ! {add,Socket};
                                            _ -> register(Channel,spawn(fun() -> listenerSocket([]) end))
                                        end,
                                    Channel ! {add, Socket},
                                    tracker ! {insert,Socket, Channel};
                                    {ok, Value} -> 
                                        Value ! {delete,Socket},
                                        tracker ! {delete,Socket},
                                        A = lists:dropwhile(fun(A) -> A /= Channel end, registered()),
                                        case A of
                                            [H|_] -> H ! {add,Socket};
                                            _ -> register(Channel,spawn(fun() -> listenerSocket([]) end))
                                        end,
                                    Channel ! {add, Socket},
                                    tracker ! {insert,Socket, Channel};
                     {message, Msg} ->  
                                tracker ! {self(),get,Socket},
                                receive 
                                    {ok, Value} -> Value ! {broadcast, Msg}
                                end
                end;
        {tcp_closed, Socket} -> io:format("Someone disconnected")
    end
end.
```

Whenever I open up a socket and point it to localhost:2266 the shell prints "Someone connected" , "Point A reached", "Point B reached" however whenever I close the socket using `tcp_gen:close/1` the server doesn't print "Someone disconnected".

Comment: Are the atoms `master` and `tracker` meant to be variables?

Comment: processes that have been registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to fix the formatting of your code, as that would show you that your `{tcp_closed, Socket}` pattern match is a `case` clause, not a `receive` clause. I think you intended it to be a clause of the outermost `receive`.

Note that the `sloop/1` function is not recursive, so that means its outermost `receive` handles only a single message, processes that message, and then returns. Perhaps you have other code you're not showing that repeatedly calls `sloop/1`, but either way, you need some kind of looping through `sloop/1`, along with moving your `{tcp_closed, Socket}` pattern match to the outermost `receive`, to allow your application to handle multiple messages correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I simply can't spot that. The `{tcp_closed, Socket}` has two ends after it. One for receive and one for the function. If it would be clause of a `case` it would surely have another `end`? Maybe I'm not seeing things very clearly here. And yes. I do have something to keep alive the process.

Comment: A normal function doesn't have an `end`. The final `end` matches the outermost `receive`, the one above it matches `case`, and the `end` just above `{tcp_closed, Socket}` matches the `receive` that starts just after `{join,Channel}`.

Comment: Ah... Why on earth would I think a function has an end. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your listener function recursively.  As written, the listener function will terminate after the first message and so won't be listening for the `gen_tcp:close` message.  You just need to re-enter the loop after processing successful messages.

```
sloop(Listen)->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    io:format("Someone connected"),
    master ! {add,Socket}, % <-- not sure what this does
    io:format("Point A reached"),
    spawn(fun() -> sloop(Listen) end),
    io:format("Point B reached").

loop_internal(Socket) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket,[{active,once}]),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} -> 
            do_your_stuff(Bin),
            %% your stuff removed for brevity
            loop_internal(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} -> io:format("Someone disconnected")
    end
end.
```